# Differences between 'target' and 'selected' properties of an event in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, event-listener

In the case of a browser event in [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/), what exactly is the difference between:

```
select.on('select', function (event) {
    let selectedFeature = event.selected[0];
}
```

and:

```
select.on('select', function (event) {
    let selectedFeature = event.target.getFeatures().item(0);
}
```

`select` being an [`ol.interaction.Select`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html) instance.

Here's an output of such event on the console:
[image: Browser console output of an event]

They seem to give the same results at first glance.
Underlying this question, I also naturally wonder if one is better than the other, or not recommended.

As a background context, I first tried for hours to figure out why the following didn't work before finding that it did work with `target` instead of `selected`:

```
select.on('select', function (event) {
    let selectedFeature = event.selected.getFeatures().item(0);
}
```

From a natural language point of view, this latter makes the most sense to me.

I have found some info on the `target` (but I do not know if this relates to the same thing than in OpenLayers) at this URL; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target but I cannot find anything on the `selected` method/property.

Comment: `selected` is an array of the features which were selected in the event, `getFeatures()` includes those and any already selected.  `target` is the object (the select interaction firing the event, so in your case `event.target.getFeatures()`  is the same as `select.getFeatures()` but `target` is useful if you use the same handler for multiple interactions.

Comment: @Mike I think your comment if of general interest and it should be put into answer.

Answer (score 2):

`selected` is an array of the features which were selected in the event, `getFeatures()` includes those and any already selected. `target` is the object (the select interaction) firing the event, so in your case `event.target.getFeatures()` is the same as `select.getFeatures()` but target is useful if you use the same handler for multiple interactions.